# XML cross-domain problems

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, cross-domain

I am building a webapplication where I need to get XML data from several cross-domain feeds.

The annoying thing is: they're cross-domain. I currently use a proxy-php script on the "local" domain, which fetches the XML from the other domain. Considering this application is being used by many users, you can probably see this is a **serious** tackle in performance.

I was wondering if it's possible to provide a way so that this proxy-script is not necessary. I do have access to the other domains, so additional scripts or w/e are an option, I just can't make the feeds run on the same domain.

Comment: Since you've got control "over the other domains", just make them include the right CORS headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` (Replace `*` with eg `https://example.com` when possible)). How do you serve the responses from your server?

Comment: Hmmm, apparently the access-control-allow-origin isn't set to * indeed. I'll see if I can edit it. Control lays through someone else though, so I'll have to contact him. Thanks for your advice! :)